# What is "q.v." in the tcsh man page

Tags: unix, tcsh, manpage

Ok, this has been an on-going annoyance, so naturally I thought to bring it here.

In the tcsh man page the phrase **q.v.** is used, and I have no clue why those four characters are inserted.

Is it self referential ? a technical reference ? a documentation or language convention ?

Here are some examples in context.

```
(+) Variables may be made read-only with `set -r' (q.v.)
```

---

```
Users who need to use the
  same set of files with both csh(1) and tcsh can have only a ~/.cshrc
  which checks for the existence of the tcsh shell variable (q.v.)
```

---

```
end-of-file (not bound)
   Signals an end of file, causing the shell to exit unless the
   ignoreeof shell variable (q.v.) is set to prevent this.  See
   also delete-char-or-list-or-eof.
```

Comment: Ha, that's great. Where else but Unix ... .

Thanks for the responses everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a language thing.  It's Latin for "quod vide", which basically says you can look up more information on the subject elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

quod vide - latin for *where to look* (for further references)

Answer (score 0):

q.v. stands for quod vide (which see) - used to reference material mentioned in text